# Tomcat logging.properties changes not being respected

Tags: web-services, tomcat, tomcat8, embedded-tomcat-8

I have a web application running on top of Tomcat 8.5.11. When I create different instances, all the instances are up and running properly. A class called TcpFailureDetector is present in Tomcat which is responsible for checking if all the instances are alive. Even though all the instances are alive, it keeps writing to log every 5 seconds and bloats the log files. This increases exponentially with the number of instances.

I came to know about logging.properties file of Tomcat. I made the change to it, to prevent logging for that one particular class as per [Tomcat official logging documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html)

```
org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector.level = OFF
```

However, these changes are inconsistent and sometimes, they take effect and sometimes, they don't work. I don't know there are inconsistencies. Is it because logging.properties configuration is being stored somewhere else even after server shutdown?

Comment: did you try restarting Tomcat service after updating the properties file?